# Outlook Plugin for group emailing

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2003

I send same email every month to around 1000 people.

Currently I am sending same mail manually to each person separately because I dont want any other person to know the emails of people to whom same mail was sent.

So is there any plugin with which I can send same email to a group but without letting the recipient know the email address of other person in a group.

Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you don't need a plug-in. You need to set up a distribution list and then BCC the distribution list. That way you only need to add the list, not each individual person.

You will have to understand the limits your email client puts on numbers of addressees so a s not to trigger spam filters.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet may be to just BCC the whole group.  None of them will see any of the other's email addresses that way.